# Using permalinks with parameters

Tags: plugins, urls, parameter

I am trying to make a custom web app with wordpress. I have a page, Person with URL http://www.domainname.com/person. In that page, i have a shortcode. This shortcode is going to extract a get parameter from the URL such as http://www.domainname.com/person?id=5. The problem is that when clicking on URL like http://www.domainname.com/person?id=5, wordpress is complaining that the page does exist when the page http://www.domainname.com/person exist. How can I solve this ?

Comment: Your permalinks don't have a trailing slash? Is the parameter you're using actually `id`? Note that WordPress has a lot of query vars that when appended to the URL will change the main query and cause 404s.

Comment: You are right, I was using a get Parameter name which was causing this problem, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

`id` is already used by WordPress, it's a query variable and a reserved name. If you put `?id=5` on the end of a URL, you're asking for the post with ID 5.

Instead, have you considered using a `person` post type? This would give you an archive, add/edit screen, admin listings, templates, individual person templates, URL paths, etc all for free No need to create a page and a page template, just use `single-person.php` and `archive-person.php`